# Git Switch Repo to Boilerplate

Tags: git, reactjs, github, boilerplate, react-starter-kit

I have been working on a project within a git repository (let's call it **Repo A**). However, as I found myself wasting far too much time fiddling around with my own build configuration, I decided to try to make use of one of the many boilerplate/starter-kit projects (let's call the one I chose **Repo B**).

Now, my issue is, how would I merge the two repositories in such a way that I retain all the history of **Repo A** without losing the ability to, later on, pull/merge updates from **Repo B**?

For reference, at the time of writing, the repositories are:
**Repo A**: https://github.com/Braden1996/tron.io/commit/33ccf5335b0b693abeaf612aa65a5658dcfe1459
**Repo B**: https://github.com/ctrlplusb/react-universally

Comment: Add the other repository as a remote, pull it, and fix all the merge conflicts

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I managed to figure this out.
For future reference, here is how:

1. Add the **Repo B** as a remote to **Repo A**:
   `git remote add repo-b repo-b.git`
2. Pull the files from our new remote:
   `git pull repo-b master --allow-unrelated-histories`
3. Resolve merge conflicts:
   `git mergetool`
4. Reset the **HEAD** - to prevent obtaining the full history of **Repo B**:
   `git reset HEAD`
5. Add all changes to be staged for the next commit:
   `git add *`
6. Commit changes:
   `git commit -m "Pull repo-b into our repo-a"`
7. Push branch:
   `git push`

To obtain future updates, start the process from step 2.